# Terraform - Dynamic variables arguments

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, aws-config

I feel like I've tried this a bunch of different ways but I may be a little off in terms of how I am calling these variables. I have the following code:

```
  config_rule_params = {
      "access_keys_rotated" = {
          "input_parameters" = "{\"maxAccessKeyAge\": \"90\"}",
          "maximum_execution_frequency" = "TwentyFour_Hours",
          "source" = {
              "owner" = "AWS",
              "source_identifier" = "ACCESS_KEYS_ROTATED"
          }
      },
      "acm_certificate_expiration_check" = {
          "input_parameters" = "{\"daysToExpiration\": \"30\"}",
          "maximum_execution_frequency" = "TwentyFour_Hours",
          "source" = {
              "owner" = "AWS",
              "source_identifier" = "ACM_CERTIFICATE_EXPIRATION_CHECK"
          },
          "scope" = {
              "compliance_resource_types" = "AWS::ACM::Certificate"
          }
      }
  }
}

resource "aws_config_config_rule" "parameterised_config_rules" {
    for_each                    = local.config_rule_params
    name                        = each.key
    input_parameters            = each.value.input_parameters
    maximum_execution_frequency = each.value.maximum_execution_frequency
    
    dynamic "source" {
        for_each = local.config_rule_params[*].source[*]
        content {
            owner = each.value.owner
            source_identifier = each.source_identifier
        }
    }

    dynamic "scope" {
        for_each = local.config_rule_params[*].scope[*]
        content {
            compliance_resource_types = each.value.compliance_resource_types
        }
    }
}
```

Eventually I will have a ton of rules added under `config_rule_params` and not all of them will have `source`, `scope` or even other parameters. How can I properly call these variables when creating my resource? Currently getting the following error:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute
  on .terraform/modules/baselines_config_rules_module/modules/baseline-config-rules/main.tf line 53, in resource "aws_config_config_rule" "parameterised_config_rules":
  53:         for_each = local.config_rule_params[*].source[*]
This object does not have an attribute named "source".
Error: Unsupported attribute
  on .terraform/modules/baselines_config_rules_module/modules/baseline-config-rules/main.tf line 61, in resource "aws_config_config_rule" "parameterised_config_rules":
  61:         for_each = local.config_rule_params[*].scope[*]
This object does not have an attribute named "scope".
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correctly using the `[*]` operator as a concise way to adapt a value that might either be null or not into a list with either zero or one elements, but there are two things to change here:

- The iterator symbol for a `dynamic` block is, by default, the name of the block you are generating. `each` is the iterator symbol for the top-level resource itself, even inside a `dynamic` block.
- As a consequence of the previous item, you can use `each.value` as part of the `for_each` expression in your `dynamic` block, to refer to the current element of `local.config_rule_params`.

Putting those together, we get something like this:

```
resource "aws_config_config_rule" "parameterised_config_rules" {
  for_each                    = local.config_rule_params

  name                        = each.key
  input_parameters            = each.value.input_parameters
  maximum_execution_frequency = each.value.maximum_execution_frequency
    
  dynamic "source" {
    for_each = each.value.source[*]
    content {
      owner             = source.value.owner
      source_identifier = source.value.source_identifier
    }
  }

  dynamic "scope" {
    for_each = each.value.scope[*]
    content {
      compliance_resource_types = scope.value.compliance_resource_types
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that in the `dynamic "source"` block the current element is `source.value`, while in the `dynamic "scope"` block the current element is `scope.value`. Because of that, it's valid to *also* use `each.value` in those `dynamic` blocks, and so you can refer to both levels of repetition together when building out these nested blocks.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for source (I'm guessing because both items had a source argument). Scope is still caught in error for the first item (access_keys_rotated, which doesn't have a scope argument): Error: Unsupported attribute - for_each = each.value.scope[*]. each.value is object with 3 attributes. This object does not have an attribute named "scope".

Comment: Got it working. Just needed to add scope + scope values to all items ("scope" = {
 "compliance_resource_types" = [ ] }, but leaving it null works just fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Indeed, because object types are defined by which attributes they have in that context an attribute that is explicitly set to `null` is _not_ the same as omitting an attribute altogether: if you omit the attribute, the value has a different object type.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `for_each` in [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html), by default the iterator is refereed to using label of the block (`source` and `scope`), rather then `each`:

> The iterator argument (optional) sets the name of a temporary variable that represents the current element of the complex value. If omitted, the name of the variable defaults to the **label of the dynamic block** ("setting" in the example above).

In your example it would be `source` and `scope`:

```
    dynamic "source" {
        for_each = local.config_rule_params[*].source[*]
        content {
            owner = source.value.owner
            source_identifier = source.source_identifier
        }
    }

    dynamic "scope" {
        for_each = local.config_rule_params[*].scope[*]
        content {
            compliance_resource_types = scope.value.compliance_resource_types
        }
    }
```